# Microsoft Dynamics AX 4.0 documentation

Tags: documentation, dynamics-ax-2012, end-of-life

Does anyone know where I can find documentation for Microsoft Dynamics AX 4.0?  It reached its end of life on 2016-10-11, and [MSDN no longer contains documentation for this product](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/fin-and-ops/get-started/ax4-content-retired).

> The Microsoft Dynamics AX 4.0 content has been retired from TechNet and MSDN.  For more information, see:
>
> - Microsoft Lifecycle Policy
> - Supported upgrade paths to Dynamics AX 2012

I've been able to find the [Quick Reference Guide](https://dynamicsuser.net/ax/m/documentation/94156), but that doesn't contain the technical information I need.  Specifically, I'm looking for the AX 4.0 equivalent of this AX 2012 guide: [Deploying Customizations Across Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 Environments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/deploying-customizations-across-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-environments-white-paper).  That document relies on `AXUtil.exe`, which does not appear to exist in AX 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've ever seen a real equivalent of the guide you linked to for AX 4.0.

If I remember correctly, for moving AX 4.0 customizations to another environment, you have two options: Exporting and importing .xpo files or copying layer files.
`AXUtil.exe` was introduced with AX 2012 to (among other things) work with models, a concept which did not exist in earlier versions.

For working with .xpo files, you can look at the AX 2012 documentation (e.g. [How to: Import Application Objects by Using the AOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/how-to-import-application-objects-by-using-the-aot)), the basics haven't changed much.

Layer files can be found in the program application folder, have the .aod extension and contain the source code (and other stuff) in a binary format. See [Where are the source files of AX stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306731/where-are-the-source-files-of-ax-stored) and [Application file extensions](http://www.artofcreation.be/2009/10/27/application-file-extensions/).

You might be able to find some of the lost TechNet and MSDN documentation for AX 4.0 with the Wayback Machine, e.g. [Dynamics AX 4.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20160311010830/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa493472.aspx). Or go old school and buy some books, e.g. [Inside Microsoft Dynamics AX 4.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735622574), which is fairly comprehensive and considered by many as The Book on Dynamics AX.